# Open source H.264 decoder in C++

Tags: h.264, decoding, live555

I am using live555 for receiving network camera video via RTSP, which data is H264 encoded. Is there any open source software for decoding the received packets and parse it into different video frames?

Best regards,

Dídac Pérez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ffmpeg can decode the data. Infact you can use ffmpeg directly recieve the data, transcode /transform it to your desired form and send it out again or dump it into a file if you wish.  If you want to use live555 for recieving it and ffmpeg for decoding simply write output of live555 to a pipe and feed it to ffmpeg to do the decoding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by your question. live 555 is built on top of ffmpeg, so it has all access to the decoders built into ffmpeg.

Comment: the statement was live 555 is built on top of ffmpeg, implying live 555 uses ffmpeg , not the other way around. Sorry for that confusion. You can built perfectly fine video players without live 555 just using ffmpeg.

Comment: That's also not correct :) live555 has no decoding functionality: it implements RTSP, RTP as well as *many* RTP payload formats, but a library such as ffmpeg is required to handle the decoding of received media. However AFAIK ffmpeg also implements RTSP, RTP, etc.

Comment: what part, never said live 555 has decoding functionality, my players are built without live 555